# Actual Call Duration Calculator in Android

Tags: android

Is there any way to calculate call duration length in Android? I understand that "the duration from HOOK_OFF to IDLE can be calculated while outgoing call" or "the duration from RINGING to IDLE can be calculated while incoming call". But I need the talk time for a call, so that I can calculate the cost of that call.

I already went through [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234147/how-to-determine-the-number-of-minutes-the-user-is-being-in-a-gsm-call?lq=1) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032542/track-a-phone-call-duration).

Comment: Yes. Android system store duration in ~Contact table or similar table. For you to get current call time you need to have you own counter. and its possible.

Comment: can you further explain "need to have you own counter" part? What counter I need to put?